# External invitations disappearing after accepting in Mac Outlook v16.49

Tags: mac-osx, outlook

Lately, I have stumbled upon a rare issue using Mac Outlook calendar invitations.

> External invitations disappear after accepting them in Mac Outlook v16.49.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Appointment are scheduled via iOS Calendar and send from our Exchange Server within the same domain. I have added 1 internal and 1 extern participant. No fancy html formatting are being used.
2. The invitation shows up just fine on the recipient **Mac Outlook v16.49**
3. After accepting the invitation the calendar item completely disappears in Outlook calendar.

- No issue accepting invitation when using iOS calendar or macOS Calendar
- No issues accepting invitation on Windows Outlook

This pretty much looks like a bug in Mac Outlook v16.49. I am not able to reproduce this issue with an old Mac Outlook 16.16.27 version.

Any workaround? Any replies are highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you encounter the calendar issue when the internal recipient accepted the invitation or the external recipient accepted the invitation, or both of the two scenarios? Did the calendar item disappear on OWA(Outlook on the web) or windows outlook after this issue happened on Mac?

Comment: Thanks. Good point. The calendar item disappears in Mac Outlook 16.49 when the invitation has been accepted from internal or external recipients. On the participant side, the calendar item remains in their calendar e.g. OWA, Webmail, iPhone iOS, Office365, Windows Outlook. It does NOT disappear when I create the invitation myself in Mac Outlook v16.49 and add the recipients. So, the way in which the invitation is created plays an essential role. This issue doesn't not occur using the same account with an old Mac Outlook 16.16.27 version.

Comment: I also tried to send meeting invitation from an Exchange account(2016) to an internal/external recipients via iOS calendar or Outlook for iOS, however, my result is different from yours: The calendar item still locates in the calendar when I accepted the invitation in mac outlook 16.49. I think you could seek help from the following website and see if others have the same issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1

Comment: @Ivan_Wang Thanks for testing. That is really strange.

Comment: Hi, It's been a while, is there update?

Comment: @Ivan_Wang Thanks, So far I do not have any updates on this.

Comment: I've the same issue with Outlook for Mac version 16.50. Does someone have a fix

Comment: Issue still there with Outlook for Mac version 16.69 - is this on the list to be fixed?

Comment: @benji Which Exchange Server are connecting to?